# Calculating row means across factor variables with strings for values

Tags: r, average

I have four variables that consist of values: Correct/Incorrect:

```
Var1      Var2      Var3      Var4 
Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct
Incorrect Incorrect Incorrect Correct
Incorrect Incorrect Correct   Incorrect
Incorrect Correct   Correct   Correct
```

I was wondering if there is an easy way to calculate average scores for each row that I can assign as a new variable. Without having to actually replace Correct/Incorrect with 1/0 in the dataset.

The score would be for correctness, so for example row1 would get a score of 1 and row4 would get a score of .75.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rowMeans`

```
df1$new_Var <- rowMeans(df1 == "Correct")
df1
#       Var1      Var2      Var3      Var4 new_Var
#1   Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct    1.00
#2 Incorrect Incorrect Incorrect   Correct    0.25
#3 Incorrect Incorrect   Correct Incorrect    0.25
#4 Incorrect   Correct   Correct   Correct    0.75
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "Var1      Var2      Var3      Var4 
Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct
Incorrect Incorrect Incorrect Correct
Incorrect Incorrect Correct   Incorrect
Incorrect Correct   Correct   Correct", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what this would look like if I was extracting the 4 variables from a larger dataset? I am familiar with rowMeans but not how to integrate the logical expression.

Comment: Sure. Can you update your question with more realistic example data? That is add two more columns and show what your real column names look like.

Comment: I believe I have figured it out. Here's what I did...
Data
df1 <- read.table(text = "Comp1 Comp2 Comp3 Comp4 Agree1 Agree2
Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct 1 2
Incorrect Incorrect Incorrect Correct 4 3
Incorrect Incorrect Correct   Incorrect 5 3
Incorrect Correct   Correct   Correct 1 1", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

rowMeans(df1[ ,c("Comp1", 
                         "Comp2", 
                         "Comp3", 
                         "Comp4")] == "Correct")
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked. You might want to try `rowMeans(df1[ ,paste0("Comp", 1:4)] == "Correct")`.